# CSS transition triggered via jQuery-added class doesn't get interrupted upon new event

Tags: jquery, css

I have a transition (`opacity` and `translate`) being triggered upon removal of a class when a scroll event fires. So far so good.

The problem is that a fast scrolling out and in the viewport area (which adds and removes the class, respectively) won't give the browser enough time to do so.

I'm not sure whether this is the correct behaviour of transitions, that is, they can't be interrupted when in progress and get restarted, or I'm forgetting something.

The issue is that it leaves the viewport area empty and it's quite clear that the class isn't removed, therefore the transition isn't reactivated, by checking the DOM in dev tools while JS does its business. I think this is probably a gap in my theory rather than code, but any help is welcome.

**Note**: I haven't reviewed the code yet, so please don't take repetition of selectors and DOM querying into account at this level, nor some comments.

The HTML is nothing but DIVs having the classes removed.

**CSS**

```
.moveOutwardLeft {
    transition: all 1700ms;
    transform: translateX(-58%);
    opacity: 0;
}

.moveOutwardRight {
    transition: all 1700ms;
    transform: translateX(58%);
    opacity: 0;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
siteSettings.$this.scroll(function () {

    var window_scrollTop = siteSettings.$this.scrollTop(),
        h2Portfolio = $("#contact").find("h2"),
        h4Offset = $("#about").find("h4").offset().top,
        downColumnMarginBottom = $(".down-column").css("margin-bottom");

    downColumnMarginBottom = parseFloat(downColumnMarginBottom);

    var leavingViewport = h2Portfolio.offset().top - downColumnMarginBottom,
        opacity = $(siteSettings.$firstChild).css("opacity");

    // Reveals the websites that leave the viewport

    if (window_scrollTop >= h4Offset && window_scrollTop < leavingViewport && opacity == 0) {

        //$(".left-side").addClass("moveInwardLeft");
        //$(".right-side").addClass("moveInwardRight");
        $(siteSettings.$firstChild).removeClass("moveOutwardLeft");
        $(siteSettings.$lastChild).removeClass("moveOutwardRight");
    }

    // Slides back and hides the websites that leave the viewport

    if (window_scrollTop >= leavingViewport || window_scrollTop < h4Offset) {

        $(".left-side").addClass("moveOutwardLeft");
        $(".right-side").addClass("moveOutwardRight");
        //$(siteSettings.$firstChild).removeClass("reveal-content");
        //$(siteSettings.$lastChild).removeClass("reveal-content");
    }

    var move = $(".first-child").hasClass("moveOutwardLeft");
    if (window_scrollTop < h4Offset || window_scrollTop >= leavingViewport && move == false) {

        $(".left-side").addClass("moveOutwardLeft");
        $(".right-side").addClass("moveOutwardRight");
    }

}); // end scroll
```

Comment: Please format your problem and share your code

Comment: could you put a working example in a fiddle please?

Answer (score 0):

I've just found the problem, the `opacity == 0` in my first condition was the cause of the problem.

By setting `opacity == 0` as condition, every time the element left the viewport it took some time for the transition to be completed, that is, to `opacity` be reset to 0. In cases where the scroll movement out and back in the viewport was faster than the time taken for the completion of the transition the condition wasn't matched resulting in the empty viewport until a new scroll event was fired inside the viewport area.